# Automation scripts using Python API for OpenStack Swift

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-swift

I am running OpenStack Swift cluster on my machines as a private cloud network, and it is working well (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE) using cURL as well CLI.

Want to write automation script for those actions, but I am not getting where/how to start.

Any suggestion for a start.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the python unittest framework. Or you can use a more declarative testing tool like https://github.com/svanoort/pyresttest.

Comment: Thank you so much! sir. I will try that tool https://github.com/svanoort/pyresttest.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the easiest way to interact with OpenStack Swift is the [python swiftclient](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-swiftclient/). Check it out.

Comment: Thank you #stefano, I did that and easy to interact with my private object storage cloud. Both Swift CLI and cURL both tools are working correctly. Now try to develop an application and will be able to do that GET, PUT, POST, DELETE operations. But where to start to develop the application.